# Schemes over $K_s$ and over $\bar{K}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $K$ be a field. Let $X$ be a scheme over $K$. We denote by $K_s$ and by $\bar{K}$ the *separable closure* and the *algebraic closure* of $K$ respectively.
By base change we have the schemes $X_{K_s}$ and $X_{\bar{K}}$. I have the following questions.

1. Is it possible that $X_{K_s}$ and $X_{\bar{K}}$ are isomorphic as schemes over $K$?
2. Is it possible to have a bijection between $X_{K_s}(K_s)$ and $X_{\bar{K}}(\bar{K})$?

In the case I need, for example, $X_\bar{K}\simeq\mathbb{G}_{m,\bar{K}}^n$, where $n$ is a positive integer and $\mathbb{G}_{m,\bar{K}}=$Spec$(\frac{\bar{K}[X,Y]}{(XY-1)})$. Is some of the previous points satisfied in this case?

Comment: If $K_s \not \cong \bar K$, then $X_{K_s}$ and $X_{\bar K}$ are schemes defined over different fields, so there is no hope for them to be isomorphic.

Comment: Moreover $X_{\bar{K}}(K_s)$ does not make sense (unless $K_s=\bar{K}$ ...).

Comment: Thank you for the observation. I edited the question. In point (1) I should have been clearer, I think that, anyway, there is no possibility for this to be true.
In point (2) I corrected my mistake. Anyway, I am fearing that also this can never be true.

Comment: Perhaps you are after the fact that base change along the map $X_{\overline{K}} \rightarrow X_{K_s}$ induces an equivalence of etale sites and moreover that pushforward and pullback along that map induce quasi-inverse equivalences of etale topoi. This is all valid for any surjective integral radiciel morphism of schemes (of which any base change of ${\rm{Spec}}(\overline{K}) \rightarrow {\rm{Spec}}(K_s)$ is an example).

Comment: The answer to question 2 is obviously NO: If $X=\mathbf A^1$ is the affine line, then $X_K(K)=K$, for every field (even, ring) $K$. So $X_{K_s}(K_s)=K_s$ and $X_{\overline K}(\overline K)=\overline K$...

Comment: I was wondering if this is true in some cases. And if it is never true why.

Comment: It is true when $X$ is locally the spectrum of an étale $K$-algebra, because base change to separably closed fields just yields a bunch of points.

Comment: @ACL I would think that the answer to 2 for the affine line would be yes, since the question is phrased in terms of bijections so it is enough that the two sets have the same cardinality, which they always do.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch: bijection! I hadn't even noticed that. As would my daughter say, WTF... :-) [PS. That's quite unfortunate that the set theory we live in allows for questions which have no mathematical sense.]

Comment: @DanielLoughran can't they be isomorphic as abstract schemes? Say, consider complex numbers as an algebra over complex numbers or real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a scheme over $K$ with $X_{\bar K}$ isomorphic to a power of the multiplicative group and you want to know if it is possible for $X_{\bar K}$ and $X_{K_s}$ to be isomorphic as $K$-schemes. The answer is no, unless $K$ is perfect. Suppose otherwise and, after replacing $K$ by a finite extension we can assume that $X$ is already isomorphic to a power of the multiplicative group and the hypothesis is that $K_s[x_1^{\pm 1},\ldots,x_m^{\pm 1}]$ is isomorphic to ${\bar K}[x_1^{\pm 1},\ldots,x_m^{\pm 1}]$ as $K$-algebras. If that's so, then the group of units of the two rings are isomorphic as groups and the elements of $K_s^*,{\bar K}^*$ respectively are the units which are divisible by all $n, (n,p)=1$, where $p$ is the characteristic. But, if $K$ is not perfect, there is an element of $K^*$ which is not arbitrarily divisible by powers of $p$ in $K_s^*$.